# Hide specific dashboard items for user in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, dashboard

In my website dashboard i have to hide Media, Comments, Contact menu items for one user who has administrator role. I googled that I have to use remove_cap function, but couldn't find enough information even to start my task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put something like this inside your functions.php. :

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'adjust_the_wp_menu', 999999 );
function adjust_the_wp_menu() {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if($user && isset($user->user_login) && 'desired_user_login' == $user->user_login)
    {
        //Remove menu items from admin area
        remove_menu_page( 'edit-comments.php' );//For comments
        remove_menu_page( 'upload.php' );//For media
        //Remove third party plugins admin menu items
        remove_menu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=your_custom_post_slug' );//for custom posts
        remove_menu_page( 'your_plugin_page_slug' );//for custom plugin's page
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Not sure what is the Contact menu in your Wordpress. I guess it is added by some plugin. You can try to figure out it's slug & use it inside the code above.

Also note, that it will only hide the menu items. Pages itself will be still available if respective url is accessed directly. To prevent this you should manage user roles or put some conditional logic into your functions.php.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what i was looking for!